# Capturing key presses for form but not for controls

Tags: .net, winforms, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a simple modal form which I'd like to close when <kbd>Esc</kbd> is pressed. It's simple doing this handling `form_KeyDown` event. The problem is the controls on the form. When the form first launched one of the buttons get focus and pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> of course doesn't do anything. Disabling `TabStop` of every button prevents this but again <kbd>Esc</kbd> stops working when any button is used. Is there a way to do this other then handling `KeyDown` of every control on the form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the `KeyPreview` property on the form to `true`, and handle the forms `previewkeydown` event.

Answer (score 8):

Does your form have a "Cancel" button?

If so set the `CancelButton` property of the form to that button.

This will close the form when <kbd>Esc</kbd> is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do more-or-less the same thing in a Compact Framework application (I wanted to have the Form capture F1..Fn keys and handle them in a global manner, while letting controls handle cursor & numeric keys).
Simon P Stevens' solution above is ideal for desktop .NET but PreviewKeyDown isn't supported by the CF. So my solution was:

- when loading a form, register each control's KeyDown handler using `For Each ctl As Control In Controls` and `AddHandler ctl.KeyDown, AddressOf OnControlKeyDown`
- Create `OnControlKeyDown` and do special processing for the Fn keys there. All other key strokes are left as-is.

This seems to be a reasonably easy way to implement this for the Compact Framework.